# Sequential route animations Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, animation, routes

I’m trying to animate between routes in Angular 2 and I’m coming up against the same issue I had in Angular 1. I would like the animations between router components to occur sequentially, so the component that is entering waits till the leaving component has completed it’s leave animation before being added to the DOM and starting it’s enter animation. By default route animations in Angular 2 occur synchronously like below

```
RouteComponent 1: Enter animation
Move to a new route
RouteComponent 2 Element added to the DOM && RouteComponent 2: Enter animation && RouteComponent 1: Leave animation
RouteComponent 1 Element removed from DOM
```

This means that if I want to give the appearance of Component 2 waiting for Component 1 to finish it’s leave animation I have to add a delay to component 2’s enter animation and position it fixed or absolute. What I really want is something like below

```
RouteComponent 1: Enter animation
Move to a new route
RouteComponent 1: Leave animation
RouteComponent 1 Element removed from DOM
RouteComponent 2 Element added to the DOM
RouteComponent 2: Enter animation
```

Has anyone managed to achieve this without adding a delay or using fixed or absolute positioning?

Comment: Hey genuinely curious -- what is your use case for needing one element completely removed before the second element can be added to the DOM?